# Accessing the iPhone/Android address book through Rhodes

Tags: android, ios, rhomobile, rhodes

Is it possible to build a library or an application with Rhodes that connects to an iPhone's/Android's native address book and uses those address books natively (e.g. still has the available API for creating groups, retrieving, updating, deleting contacts etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see all available PIM API interaction in the Rho documentation [here](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#pim-contacts).  If what you want to do (e.g. groups) is not yet available, consider contacting the developers with an enhancement request, which you can track on [their Pivotal Tracker project](https://www.pivotaltracker.com/projects/45686/stories).

Answer (score 0):

Add 'pim' capability to app's build.yml

```
capabilities:
  - pim
```

Then it is possible to work with contacts from ruby:

```
contact = {'first_name' => 'Alexey', 'email_address' => 'alexey@aaaaa.org'}
contact = Rho::RhoContact.create!(contact)

contacts = Rho:RhoContact.find(:all)
```

See more details at official [Rhodes docs](http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#pim-contacts).